# Lower Bound on Expected Maximum and Upper Bound on Expected Minimum of Order Statistics

Tags: order-statistics, stochastic-ordering

This question relates to bounds on expectations of order statistics, elaborated upon in the Book by Arnold and Balakrishnan (1989). Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables distributed on a positive and finite interval $[0,a]: a \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Denote by $\mu_i=E[X_i]$ and $\sigma_i^2=var(X_i)$. Let $F$ denote the corresponding parent CDF, and $\mu,\sigma^2$ denote it's associated mean and variance. Furthermore, let $X_{1:n}\leq X_{2:n}\leq \ldots\leq X_{n:n}$ denote the corresponding order statistics with expectations $\mu_{1:n},\ldots,\mu_{n:n}$. Under homogeneity assumptions (i.e., $\forall i:\mu_i=\mu,\sigma_i^2=\sigma^2$) we may bound the expectations of a general order statistic as follows:

$$-\sigma \sqrt{\frac{n-i}{i}}\leq\mu_{i:n}-\mu\leq\sigma \sqrt{\frac{i-1}{n-i+1}},$$

defined by Theorem 3.19, Arnold and Balakrishnan (1989). In the particular case of $n=2$, the lower bound on the maximum and the upper bound on the minimum are trivial cases since,
$$-\sigma \leq\mu_{1:2}-\mu\leq0, \mathrm{\quad and\quad}0\leq\mu_{2:2}-\mu\leq\sigma,$$provide no useful information in terms of variance.

The extension of Hawkings (1971) on the bounds of extreme order statistics is applicable only in the deterministic case. An extension to distributions defined on a positive interval from Papados (1996) is defined without variance. In a recent paper Rychlik (2014) shows that the bound $$\frac{\mu_{1:n}-\mu}{\sigma}\leq 0$$ is achievable also in increasing density (ID) and increasing failure rate (IFR) distributions. As to my reading (although it seems counter-intuitive), the above bounds on extreme order statistics seem to hold.

In the particular problem I have in mind, I need a mean-variance bound on the ratio of the extreme order statistics. From the above inequalities, one could derive that

$$1\leq\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}}\leq\frac{\mu+\sigma}{\mu-\sigma}.$$

The obtained lower bound is very trivial since, at least to my understanding, the lower bound should also depend on the mean and variance. Intuitively, an increase in the variance would push the expectations of the order statistics away from the mean (which may not be centered). How could a mean-variance lower bound on the ratio of extreme order statistics for a broad class (possibly IFR) of distributions look like?